# BLE data receiving android app through BLE notification

Tags: java, android-studio

I have a BLE device which sends out data continuously as a notification. I am very new to android app development, I just installed android studio today.

I need to develop an app that receives such data and stores in a CSV file or whatever or even better if its stores in the cloud server. Is there any example which I can start from?

I tried getting build in project from android example but those are quite different from my requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You'll be looking for a foreground service...

here is a basic one to get you started, feel free to ask me any questions.

https://github.com/REInVent650/foreground-service-base

Comment: Can you provide me with a simpler code ?

Comment: as far as I'm aware this is the bare minimum code you will need to run a foreground service. You will need to add more code to handle the bluetooth connection and interact with the device filesystem or a server